# aws boto3 access denied when using remote interpreter in pycharm

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pycharm, boto3

I am able to access S3 via boto3 on an ec2 machine, but when I connect via pycharm to the remote interpreter on that exact machine, I get Access Denied.
I do not think it is the remote interpreter - when I connect to the host via the pycharm terminal, I still get Access Denied. So it looks like there is some pycharm related issue that I am unable to identify.

Comment: Are the AWS credentials available in the env used by pycharm?

Comment: @insti good point. trying to make the credentials shared across sessions... thanks

Comment: a note for the next person looking at this, pycharm connects to the interpreter via sftp, which does not source .profile. so best to configure ~/.aws/credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a note for the next person looking at this, pycharm connects to the interpreter via sftp, which does not source .profile. so best to configure ~/.aws/credentials